# Limitar a las últimas n iteraciones los valores (enteros) añadidos a un diccionario mediante el uso de clases

Tags: python-3.x

Dispongo de un código que realiza una serie de operaciones que simulan un intercambio de "señales" entre jugadores (ver código).

Estoy intentando implementar en este código una funcionalidad adicional para que en cada simulación del juego, tan sólo las señales producidas en las últimas x rondas sean consideradas en la memoria de cada jugador. El límite de señales guardadas en la memoria vendría entonces declarado en la variable `menLen` dentro de `def main`.

En el juego, cada ronda, cada jugador muestra una señal y observa una señal. Cada jugador tiene una memoria de señales observadas `men_observadas` y una memoria de señales producidas `mem_mostradas`. En ambos casos, esto se almacena en diccionarios. Por ejemplo, si el diccionario de memoria observada es `{'S1': 1, 'S2': 0, 'S3': 0, 'S4': 0}`, esto significa que el jugador i ha guardado en su memoria la señal 1 una vez. Si tenemos `{'S1': 2, 'S2': 0, 'S3': 0, 'S4': 0}` ha observado la S1 dos veces. Idem para `mem_mostradas`.

De este modo, si declaro `menLen = 1`, los jugadores del juego deberían guardar en sus diccionarios de memorias tan solo los valores correspondientes a la última ronda (es decir, debería aparecer un máximo de 1 valor (número entero) para el total de claves del diccionario de memoria). Sin embargo, actualmente, tal y como puede observarse al imprimir `print(self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas)`, los diccionarios de memoria van acumulando los valores producidos en todas las rondas.

Sé por previas versiones que esto podía ser implementado fácilmente utilizando la librería `collections` y la función `deque`. La clase para implementar esta funcionalidad en una versión anterior era algo así:

```
class player():
    def __init__(self, menLen):
        self.mem_mostradas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
        self.men_observadas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
```

Pero últimamente, con ayuda de la comunidad he mejorado el código y con ello la estructura de datos de `mem_mostradas` y `mem_observadas`, por lo que la clase que utilizaba anteriormente no se ajusta a las demandas de la estructura de datos actual.

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random, seed
from bisect import bisect
from collections import deque

def choice(opciones, probs):
    probAcumuladas = list()
    aux = 0
    for p in probs:
        aux += p
        probAcumuladas.append(aux)
    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]


class Jugador:
    def __init__(self, nombre, senales, sigma, b, x, m):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.senales = senales
        self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.sigma = sigma[:]  # Hacer copia para que cada jugador tenga la suya
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m

    def __str__(self):
        return "Jugador_{}".format(self.nombre)

    def with_b(self, muestra, observa, r, idx):
        result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * self.b * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        return result

    def choose(self, r):
        probs = [
            self.with_b(
                self.mem_mostradas[op], self.men_observadas[op], r, indx
            )
            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)
        ]
        elecc = choice(self.senales, probs)
        return elecc


class Partida:
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, sigmas, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.jugadores = {
            nombre: Jugador(nombre, senales, sigmas[nombre], b, x, m)
            for nombre in jugadores
        }
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()

    def generar_senales(self):
        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores, self.senales))
        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = {}
            for jugador in self.jugadores.values():
                eleccs[jugador.nombre] = jugador.choose(r)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for ronda in self.emparejamientos:
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)
            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                print(self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas)


def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]
    emparejamientos = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(1, 3), (2, 4)], [(1, 4), (2, 3)]]
    menLen=1

    s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    sigmas = {1: s1, 2: s1, 3: s1, 4: s1}

    muestras = [{"b": 0.0, "x": 0.5, "m": 0.02}]

    muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(1)]

    simulaciones = 1

    for sim in range(simulaciones):
        for mu in range(len(muestras)):
            juego = Partida(
                jugadores,
                emparejamientos,
                senales,
                sigmas,
                muestras[mu]["b"],
                muestras[mu]["x"],
                muestras[mu]["m"]
            )
            juego.jugar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Objetivo**

- Ayuda para una correcta implementación de una clase que limite el número de valores añadidos a la memoria de los agentes a las últimas x rondas deseadas.

Comment: Agradezco sugerencias para editar esta pregunta y que así sea más clara y comprensible para la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### El problema

Si no entiendo mal lo que al final necesitas es un diccionario con las cuentas de las señales vistas, pero esas señales han de ser sólo las correspondientes a los últimos N turnos.

Es decir, si por ejemplo las posibles señales son `[ 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4' ]` y se guardan solo los últimos 5 turnos y las señales vistas en ellos fueron (la más antigua a la izquierda, la más nueva a la derecha)

```
S1, S1, S1, S4, S2
```

el diccionario valdría  `{ 'S1': 3, 'S2': 1,  'S3': 0, 'S4': 1}`

Pero si a continuación se observa la señal `'S3'`, ya que solo se guardan las cinco últimas, la primera S1 observada (la más antigua) debe desaparecer, con lo que las cinco últimas observaciones serían:

```
S1, S1, S4, S2, S3
```

y el diccionario ahora tendría que ser `{ 'S1': 2, 'S2': 1,  'S3': 1, 'S4': 1}`

### La solución

Creo que no hay forma de construir el diccionario en cuestión por si solo, a base de sumar 1 a las nuevas observaciones, pues eventualmente habrá que restar 1 también a alguna de ellas y sin un histórico de cuál es la más antigua no sabríamos cuál decrementar.

Por tanto tu idea de usar una `deque` me parece adecuada, ya que esta estructura de datos permite ir introduciendo valores por la derecha y si se excede el tamaño máximo permitido automáticamente irá eliminando valores por la izquierda.

Lo que habrá que hacer será tener una `deque` que actúe como histórico de lo visto, y combinarlo con un contador (`collections.Counter()`) para contar cuántas veces aparece cada señal en el histórico.

Es mejor por tanto hacer responsable a la clase `Jugador` del mantenimiento de estos contadores, en lugar de permitir a `Partida` que los incremente directamente.

Haríamos por tanto un nuevo método en la clase jugador, que se ocupe de memorizar la última señal jugada y la última señal vista, y con ellas actualice su histórico y el diccionario de contadores, así:

```
class Jugador:
    def __init__(self, nombre, senales, sigma, b, x, m, menLen):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.senales = senales
        self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.__mem_mostradas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
        self.__men_observadas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
        self.sigma = sigma[:]  # Hacer copia para que cada jugador tenga la suya
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m

    def memoriza(self, mostrada, observada):
        self.__mem_mostradas.append(mostrada)
        self.__men_observadas.append(observada)
        mostradas = Counter(self.__mem_mostradas)
        observadas = Counter(self.__men_observadas)
        self.mem_mostradas = { signal: mostradas.get(signal, 0) for signal in self.senales }
        self.mem_observadas = { signal: observadas.get(signal, 0) for signal in self.senales }

    # El resto de la clase Jugador no se toca
```

Fíjate cómo en `__init__()` hace falta un nuevo parámetro `memLen` que se usa para inicializar las `deque` (las cuales he llamado `__mem_mostradas` y `__men_observadas`, comenzando por doble guión bajo para indicar que son atributos "privados" de la clase, que no deberían ser accedidos desde fuera). A la vez he conservado los diccionarios originales `mem_mostradas` y `men_observadas`, para que no haya que tocar el resto de funciones. El nuevo método `memoriza` se ocupa de actualizar correctamente ese diccionario, en base a lo que haya en las deques privadas.

El resto del código apenas precisa modificaciones. Al instanciar los `Jugador`es tendrás que pasarles el nuevo parámetro `menLen`, por ejemplo:

```
class Partida:
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, sigmas, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.jugadores = {
            nombre: Jugador(nombre, senales, sigmas[nombre], b, x, m, menLen=5) # <----
            for nombre in jugadores
        }
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()
```

(he puesto un 5 directamente a modo de ejemplo, pero puedes hacer que ese valor lo reciba como parámetro el constructor de la `Partida`)

Y el otro cambio que tienes que hacer es donde, desde `Partida.jugar` accedías directamente al diccionario de contadores de los jugadores. Ahora debes invocar `Jugador.memoriza()` en su lugar. Aquí:

```
class Partida:

   # ...

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for ronda in self.emparejamientos:
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)
            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                # Esto es lo que se cambia
                self.jugadores[jugador1].memoriza(observada=senales[jugador2], mostrada=senales[jugador1])
                self.jugadores[jugador2].memoriza(observada=senales[jugador1], mostrada=senales[jugador2])
```

Comment: @abufalia gracias. Sí, comprendiste muy bien lo que se buscaba. Excelente respuesta. Por si algún usuario iniciático desea utilizar este código, debe invocarse `menLen` dentro de main cuando se llama a `Partida` al iniciar el juego, ya que ahora hay un parámetro más.